# Can't turn on again for remote participants in Twilio

Tags: reactjs, twilio

In Twilio Programmable Video API, I want to add mic on/off features to my application. Almost all my code is based in [this code](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js/blob/master/quickstart/src/index.js). I have successfully built web P2P calling still but it could not turn on/off...

My code:

```
onTurnCam = () => {
  const { turnCam, turnMic, previewTracks } = this.state;
  if (turnCam === true) {
    const videoTracks = previewTracks[1];
    videoTracks.stop();
    this.setState({ turnCam: false });
  } else {
    previewTracks.forEach(this.detachTrack);
    if (turnMic === true) {
      createLocalTracks({ audio: true, video: true }).then(tracks => {
        this.setState({ previewTracks: tracks });
        const previewContainer = document.getElementById("local-media");
        this.attachTracks(tracks, previewContainer);
      });
    } else {
      createLocalTracks({ audio: false, video: true }).then(track => {
        this.setState({ previewTracks: track });
      });
    }
    this.setState({ turnCam: true });
  }
};
```

My local Preview is changeable but for remote people it shows my cam freezed... I would like to know the opposite method fot `track.stop()` if existed. I can't make sense how `local tracks` might be sent remote again.

Answer (score 0):

This is best pracetice:

```
  onTurnCam = () => {
    const { turnCam, activeRoom } = this.state;
    if (turnCam === true) {
      if (activeRoom) {
        const localParticipant = activeRoom.localParticipant;
        localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach(function(videoTrack) {
          videoTrack.track.disable();
        });
      }
      this.setState({ turnCam: false });
    } else {
      if (activeRoom) {
        const localParticipant = activeRoom.localParticipant;
        localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach(function(videoTrack) {
          videoTrack.track.enable();
        });
      }
      this.setState({ turnCam: true });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const toggleVoice = () => {                                // Voice toggle event handler
       if (voiceStatus === "Mute") {
           room.localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach(audioTrack => {
               audioTrack.track.disable();
           });
           setVoiceStatus("Unmute");
       } else {
           room.localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach(audioTrack => {
               audioTrack.track.enable();
           });
           setVoiceStatus("Mute");
       }
   }

   const toggleVideo = () => {                             // Video toggle event handler
       if (videoStatus === "Stop Video") {
           room.localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach(videoTrack => {
               videoTrack.track.disable();
           });
           setVideoStatus("Start Video");
       } else {
           room.localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach(videoTrack => {
               videoTrack.track.enable();
           });
           setVideoStatus("Stop Video");
       }
   }
```

This is what I did before.